# Question on estimates

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations

I have question on Theorem $1$ of Evan's book page $329$ or ($6.3$ Regularity).

At the part $6$, Evan wrote:

> We finally combine $(12),(20)$ and $(22),$ to discover
>
> $$\int_V |D^h_k Du|^2 dx \leq \int_U \zeta^2 |D^h_k Du|^2 dx \leq C \int_U f^2 +u^2 +|Du|^2 dx$$ for $k=1,...,n$ and all sufficiently small $|h| \not = 0.$
>
> In view of Theorem $3(ii)$ in $\S 5. 8.2$, we deduce $Du \in H^1_{loc} (U; \mathbb{R}^n),$ and thus $u \in H^2_{loc}(U),$ with the estimate
>
> $$\|u\|_{H^2(V)} \leq C (\|f\|_{L^2(U)}+\|u\|_{H^1(U)}).$$

I know why $Du \in H^1_{loc} (U; \mathbb{R}^n).$ But I do not understand why we will have the estimate $\|u\|_{H^2(V)} \leq C (\|f\|_{L^2(U)}+\|u\|_{H^1(U)}).$ Can someone explain to me?

Comment: I don't have Theorem 3(ii) in front of me, but I bet it includes some norm estimates, and this is it. The $L^2$-estimate for $D^h_k D u$ you have above apply to $D D u$ as well.

Comment: Yeah I know that we can estimate $D D u$ in $L^2$ by $D^h_k D u$ from the theorem $3(ii).$ However, I do not understand how he can pass the square root into the summation.

Comment: This is simply $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \le a+b$, isn't it?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Yes, it is. I was so confused about plus and integral sign